# .animate queue with multiple animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to make a div move from the bottom of the screen to the top, starting with opacity 0, having opacity 1 in the middle and fading again to 0 at the top.
Everything has to start with 3s delay.

```
        $("#circle")
                .css({'display':'block'})
                .css({'opacity': '0'})
                .css({'top':$(window).height()})
                .delay(3000)
                .animate({'opacity':1},{duration:1000},"linear")
                .animate({'top':$(window).height()/2},{duration:1000, queue:false},"linear")                
                .animate({'opacity':0},{duration:1000},"linear")
                .animate({'top':0},{duration:1000, queue:false},"linear")
```

I also tried with 'queue:false' but it still does not run properly, and this is also not linear.
Any ideas?

Comment: What is the problem? you have requirements + code, but no question

Comment: why isnt your default #circle css (display etc) set in the css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make better use of the object notation, such as :

```
     $("#circle")
                .css({
                      'display':'block',
                      'opacity': '0',
                      'top':$(window).height()
}
)
                .delay(3000)
                .animate({ 
                           'opacity':1 , 
                           'top':$(window).height()/2
                         },
                         {duration:1000},"linear")
                .delay(1000)
                .animate({
                          'opacity':0,
                          'top':0
                         },
                         {duration:1000},"linear");
```

You could try this or try to set delays between multiple lines using the `$(this)` selector.

Best of luck, it always help to have a jsfiddle link.

Comment: Thanks! So the delays were the problem. This did not produce the linear animation thought so I chaged it to: .delay(3000)
    .animate({
    'top':$(window).height()/2,
 'opacity': '1'
  }, 2000, 'linear', function() {  
    $(this).animate({
     'top':0,
  'opacity': '0'
    }, 2000, 'linear');
 });